# Vendored gems not getting picked up by passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, passenger

In my app, I've vendored the json-1.1.6 gem and in environment.rb file, its mentioned

```
config.gem "json", :version => '1.1.6'
```

When I try to access via browser, the following error is shown by passenger.

```
Error message:
can't activate json (= 1.1.7, runtime) for [], already activated json-1.1.6 for ["dancroak-twitter-search-0.5.5"]
```

And in my dev machine, gem list show

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

json (1.1.7)
json_pure (1.1.7)
```

But since the gem is vendored with the version of 1.1.6, it should take the precedence, right?
Coz when booting via script/server (Mongrel), the app runs smoothly.

Have anybody been through such kinda situation??

Comment: A little more backtrace would be handy, try running a rake task with --trace.
Sounds like something is calling `gem "json"` somewhere… very odd. It could be due to json being a special case, as (iirc) it's vendorized within rails too.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe dancroak-twitter-search has a hard dependency on 1.1.7 specifically?